# How do I plot results of complicated calculations in Mathematica?

Tags: list-manipulation, graphics, plotting

I am new to *Mathematica* and am struggling with making plots of how features of solutions vary with parameters. For example, I can find the eigenvalues and zeroes of a Sturm Liouville problem (showing just the first nonzero eigenvalue for this example) with

```
sol = NDSolve[
{g''[x] - 
   4*c*(-((3 r sigma^3)/(L - x)^4) + (3 sigma^3)/(L + x)^4)*
    g'[x] + mu[x]*g[x] == 0, mu'[x] == 0,
 g[-b] == 1, g'[-b] == 0, g'[b] == 0},
{g, mu}, x,
Method -> {"EventLocator", "Event" -> g[x], 
  "EventAction" :> 
   Print["mu= ", lambda = mu[x], ",  g[", zero = x, "] = ", 
    g[x]]}
]
```

but I would like to see how these features vary with the parameters.  Looking at the basic help files that come with *Mathematica*, I can loop over parameters using `Do[(block of code given above),{c,cstart,cend,dc},{r,rstart,rend,dr}]` etc.  But then the documentation tells me how to make graphs by either typing thousands of numbers in curly braces or reading them from a file (of not obviously documented format).

I've spent two hours trying to store these numbers in arrays that `ListPlot3d` will recognize but I either get error messages when trying to create the arrays or error messages when `ListPlot3d` tries to read them.  The closest I have come to success is writing the results to a sequential file

```
sfile = OpenWrite["zero.dat"]; Do[....
Write[sfile, {r, c, zero}]
....
Close[sfile]
z_list = Import["zero.dat", "Table"]
```

This gets the numbers in and out.  If the imported data is displayed in table form it looks like a table of x,y,z data for `ListPlot3d`.  But when I try to run it I get

```
In[55]:= ListPlot3D[z_list]
```

> ```
> During evaluation of In[55]:= Rule::rhs: Pattern z_list appears on the right-hand side of rule System`ProtoPlotDump`modelData$26641[WrappedValues,z_list,Charting`Private`Tag$26644]->z_list. >>
>
> During evaluation of In[55]:= ListPlot3D::arrayerr: z_list must be a valid array or a list of valid arrays. >>
>
> Out[55]= ListPlot3D[z_list]
> ```

The idea that I have to write results to a file to plot them sounds like I should be invoking WATFOR.  There must be an elegant way to plot the results of complex calculations, but in two hours looking through help (and google), I haven't found it.  How do I do this?

Comment: What version of *Mathematica* do you have?  Since version 9, there is `ParametricNDSolve` and `WhenEvent` has replaced `"EventLocator"`.

Comment: You shouldn't use `_` in parameter names. What happens if you replace your `z_list` with, e.g., `zList`?

Comment: Or to interactively vary the parameters and see the effects, use `Manipulate`.  http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Manipulate.html

Comment: Your code is confusing, but at the very least you can simplify it by replacing the constraint mu'[x] == 0 with mu == mu0 (a constant).  Don't compound problems by worrying about how to read and write variables (Import and Export).  Give us the simplest version of your code that works.

Comment: I would be careful manipulating the parameters of a differential equation, at least don't do it entirely naively. You should at least set `SynchronousUpdating->False` if you encounter issues. You might consider starting with `sol[r_,sigma_,L_]:=` and plot `g[t]` against `r` for fixed values of `sigma` and `L`.. or whatever it is you are looking for.

Comment: Have you looked at the help file for NDSolve? There are many examples there that plot the output of the ODE. Maybe you could mimic one of these?

Comment: Thanks! Getting rid of the underscore does wonders--it now reads the data.  It still feels like a kludge, but a kludge is better than an error.  As for mu'[x]==0, that is a suggestion from AdvancedNumericalDifferentialEquationSolvingInMathematica.pdf as a simple way to solve for the eigenvalue mu. I am using version 10.0.2.  I am not using ParametricNDSolve because it will not let me vary the parameter "L" (which specifies the domain of the eigenfunction -- a physically interesting phenomenon).  I will try the delayed function--if nothing else it looks like a good learning experience.

Answer (score 2):

I woudl suggest defining your soulutions as a delayed function using SetDelayed (":=")

```
sol[c_, sigma_, L_, r_, b_] := ...
```

Now you can go ahead and generate a table of solutions like that:

```
sols = ParallelTable[sol[c, sigma, L, r, b], {c, cmin, cmax, dc}, {sigma, sigmamin, sigmamax, dsigma}, {L, Lmin, Lmax, dL}, {r, rmin, rmax, dr}, {b, bmin, bmax, db}]
```

and access a solution within sols by **index** such that

```
sols[[1,2,3,4,5]]
```

yields

```
sol[cmin + 0*dc, sigmamin + 1*dsigma, Lmin + 2*dL, rmin + 3*dr, bmin + 4*db]
```

you can also take subsets of the table you created and listplot them.
I hope I understood your problem right.

PS: since your problem comes with 5 Parameters you get a 5 dimensional result wich is hard to plot, plotting subsets might be a solution. A good way to plot up to 3 dimensional results is using Image3D[].